# How to select from expression?

Tags: sql-server

In PostgreSQL I can issue next query:

```
=> select 6 between 5 and 7;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

But if I run similar expression in Microsoft SQL server I get the error:

```
> select 6 between 5 and 7;
Server message number=156 severity=15 state=1 line=8 server=WIN-P5BDUH0CU0N text=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'
```

How to select from expression in Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: You might want to explain what that query does. We can't explain to you how to achieve same behaviour if you don't explain what that behaviour is. Why does `6` end up with the value `t`, for example? Where does the `t` come from?

Comment: use CASE instead

Comment: @ThomA: 't' is the true value in postgresql. Result is true, because 5<6<7 is true. I want to run expressions. This is more simple; `select 1`

Comment: @Horaciux: May you please provide an example?

Comment: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) @EugenKonkov . Or, alternatively, [IIF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which is a short-hand `CASE` expression.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, so unclear what you want. Maybe `SELECT IIF(6 between 5 and 7, 1, 0);`

Comment: SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 6 BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 't'
        ELSE 'f'
    END AS Result;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @ThomA and @Charlieface. Next expression works fine for me:

```sql
select IIF( 8 between 5 and 7, 1, 0 );
```

@Horaciux query is what I was looking for:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 6 BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END AS Result;
```